# .desktop files with custom icons

Tags: icons, cmake, vala, freedesktop.org

I created an app and custom icon for it. I succesfully installed and stuff and when I add a path to the Icon path into the .dekstop file like this:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/resize.svg
```

it works fine but with `Icon=resize` it does not. My app icon is just the default one.

I installed the icons with the following command in the cmakelists.txt and I checked the icons too, they are copied so everything should be fine. What do I miss?

```
install (FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/icons/16/resize.svg DESTINATION share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps)
install (FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/icons/24/resize.svg DESTINATION share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps)
install (FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/icons/32/resize.svg DESTINATION share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps)
install (FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/icons/48/resize.svg DESTINATION share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps)
install (FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/icons/64/resize.svg DESTINATION share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps)
install (FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/icons/128/resize.svg DESTINATION share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps)
```

Comment: The icon lookup mechanism is described here: http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#icon_lookup

Comment: Here is some documentation as well: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/icons.html.en

Comment: Your paths seem sane to me, did you try `Icon=resize.svg`?

Comment: ... resize.svg for some reason worked... It didn't in the past(or maybe I hallucinated it) :D Thank you! The lookup mechanism did not help me and I'll take a look on the documentations later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from the documentation I read on the subject `Icon=resize` should work fine.

Apparently it does not work in your case. (Maybe you should ask someone from you Linux distribution in a bug report or on a mailing list).

`Icon=resize.svg` is more specific. (See comments on the question)